# environment variable parsing in jenkins groovy script on windows

Tags: jenkins-groovy

In jenkins, when it runs my job there are several svn checkouts. Each of these results in an environment variable SVN_REVISION_N where N is the checkout index. I want to parse all of these and find the highest revision.

Answer (score 0):

While unable to find a method using the Groovy script, a method using cmd batch is

```
VERIFY OTHER 2>nul
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO Unable to enable extensions
SET /a max_svn=0
SET /a index=1
:loop
    r = "SVN_REVISION_"%index%
    if defined r (
        SET /a xxv=%r%
        IF %xxv% gtr %max_svn% (
            SET /a max_svn=%xxv%
        )
    )
    else (
        goto all_done
    )
    goto loop
:all_done
echo max_svn=%max_svn%
```

Any pointers on improvements appreciated, as this windows cmd scripting is very primitive.